Losing audiovisual sync when processing an animated GIF with ImageIO and PIL
I am trying to chromakey a GIF and the result is weird. The GIF should have a framerate of 30 FPS, but when I put the chromakeyed and transparent frames back together the GIF isn't what it should be. The GIF displays a waveform which should sync up to a specific song. When I play the input GIF under the waveform it does sync up correctly, the output GIF does not. It feels like it's to fast, or even the frames are not in order. It is hard to describe but the GIF changes rapidly, the "loudness" of the waveform starts earlier than the song gets "loud". This is the code I am using to chromakey and save the frames.
The code used to get the frames:
import imageio
import numpy as np
import os
from PIL import Image

def chromakey(image, color, tolerance):
    if image.mode != 'RGBA':
        image = image.convert('RGBA')
    data = np.array(image)
    color = np.array(color)[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]
    lower_bound = color - tolerance
    upper_bound = color + tolerance
    mask = np.all(np.logical_and(data[:, :, :3] >= lower_bound, data[:, :, :3] <= upper_bound), axis=-1)
    data[mask] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    return Image.fromarray(data)

def extract_frames(input_path, output_folder, color, tolerance):
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)

    gif = imageio.get_reader(input_path)

    for i, frame in enumerate(gif):
        frame = Image.fromarray(frame)
        processed_frame = chromakey(frame, color, tolerance)
        frame_path = os.path.join(output_folder, f"frame_{i:03d}.png")
        processed_frame.save(frame_path)

input_gif_path = 'input.gif'
output_folder = 'frames'
black_color = (0, 0, 0)
tolerance = 25

extract_frames(input_gif_path, output_folder, black_color, tolerance)


The code to combine them to a GIF again:
import os
from PIL import Image

def read_frames_from_folder(folder):
    # Get a sorted list of frame files
    frame_files = sorted([f for f in os.listdir(folder) if f.endswith('.png')])
    frames = []
    for frame_file in frame_files:
        frame_path = os.path.join(folder, frame_file)
        frame = Image.open(frame_path)
        frames.append(frame)
    return frames

def create_gif_from_frames(frames, output_gif_path, fps):
    # Calculate duration per frame based on FPS
    duration = int(1000 / fps)  # Duration in milliseconds
    
    # Save the frames as a new GIF with disposal=2
    frames[0].save(output_gif_path, save_all=True, append_images=frames[1:], duration=duration, loop=0, disposal=2)

output_folder = 'frames'
output_gif_path = 'output.gif'
fps = 20  # Set the desired FPS here

# Read frames from folder
frames = read_frames_from_folder(output_folder)

# Create GIF from frames
create_gif_from_frames(frames, output_gif_path, fps)


Here is what the original GIF looks like:
https://streamable.com/qcut9l
And here is the processed one:
https://streamable.com/ff1aq4
Thank you in advance!
I tried to change the framerate, but that still gave me the same problem, just more choppy.
Then I checked the metadata of the output GIF which has the correct duration.
I then thought the problem may not be in the part where the GIF is generated but where the frames are generated, but the amount of frames generated is correct too. Asking ChatGPT-4o didn't help anything and I didn't find any answers online either.

"Isn't what it should be" isn't a narrow, specific, technical problem. We really want questions to have everything needed to understand what's being asked included in the question text itself; is it not possible to build a description of what's wrong in the text of the question, as opposed to asking folks to follow links before they have even a general understanding of what specific problem your question is about?

(Doing chromakey well is hard! In particular, despill logic is necessary to have credibly professional-looking results, and even backdrop lighting is called for to make more naive implementations work reasonably; can't say if any of that is closely related to your problem, though, because right now the description doesn't permit for understanding the question without following external links -- and as someone who lived through the goatse days, I don't do that).

I will update the question shortly, sorry for the confusion and missunderstanding

Thank you! If the problem is with AV sync -- can you reproduce it without any chromakey logic at all? Also, I'd generally suggest looking at the per-frame timings on both input and output -- in an animated GIF, each frame can specify a specific time when it's supposed to be displayed, so there isn't necessarily a constant framerate at all. Ideally, one would want to copy those exact timings from input to output instead of assuming that there is a framerate that the original is synchronized to.

Relevant: imageio individual frame rates -- note the ability to provide per-frame duration instead of specifying fps; if you copy those individual durations from the input to the output, I'd expect that to address the issue.

Thank you very much! I'll definitely try out your suggestions and edit the question accordingly.
